# Split text file into several parts by character

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text-files, streamreader

I apologise in advance if there is already an answer to this problem; if so please just link it (*I have looked, btw! I just didn't find anything relating to my specific example*) :)

I have a text (`.txt`) file which contains data in the form `1.10.100.0.200` where 1, 10, 100, 0 and 200 are numbers storing the map terrain layout of a game. This file has multiple lines of `1.10.100.0.200` where each line represents an item  of terrain in the map.

Here is what I would like to know:

- How do I find out how many lines there are, so I know how many items of terrain to create when I read the map file?
- What is the method I should use to get each of 1, 10, 100, 0 and 200:

E.g. when I am translating the file into a map terrain at runtime I might use the `terrainitem1.Location = New Point(x, y)` or `terrainitem1.Size = New Size(p, q)` commands, where `x`, `y`, `p` and `q` are integers or doubles relating to the terrain's location or size. Where would I then find `x`, `y` etc. out of 1, 10, 100, 0 and 200, if say `x` is equal to 1, `y` to 10 and so on?

I am sorry if this isn't clear, please just ask me and I'll try to explain.

N.B. I am using VB.NET WinForms

Comment: edit your post to provide some actual data in its actual format instead of `a.b.c.d.e` and then `a,b,c,d,e`.

Comment: @Plutonix as I see it, the data format is `a.b.c.d.e`. He uses commas just to explain what the elements are, not because the data comes that way.

Comment: Exactly @JoshPart. Oh well, I've improved it now. Care to look again?

Comment: clear as mud: there are 5 values there but what do they represent? what is the layout?  *how* does `1.10.100.0.200` represent an item?  there are too many elements to be a `Point` and `Size`, what order are they in?

Comment: @user3740891 Do you already know how to read the file? Or do you want to know both how to [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) the lines and then [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) them?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. I want the item's ID to be 1 (the first number), its height to be 10 (the second number), its width to be 100 (the third number), its location's x to be the 0 (the fourth number), and its location's y to be 200 (the last number). I'm merely using a dot to separate the values while using only one file/line. I'm saying first, second etc because other items will have to use the same structure, preferably within a `For`/`Next` loop in order to be more code-efficient.

Comment: @JoshPart I know how to read the file, but I don't know how to separate the string created to separate into the above-mentioned parts. Having said that, a solution from reading to using would be useful just to have an oversight.

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit, because editing to add *(ANSWERED)* in the title and a solution in the text is improper here. It's fine if you want to post a self- answer, but you need to do it properly. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for information about how to do so.

Comment: @Ken thanks. I thought about it, but wasn't sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know how many lines a file has without opening the file and reading its contents.

You didn't indicate how far you've got on this. Do you know how to open a file?

Here's some basic code to do what you want. (Sorry, this is C# but the idea is the same in VB.)

```
string line;

using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\filename.txt"))
{
    // Read each line from the file (until null returned)
    while ((line = myTextReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Get each number in line (as string)
        string[] values = line.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // Convert each number to integer
        id = int.Parse(values[0]);
        height = int.Parse(values[1]);
        width = int.Parse(values[2]);
        x = int.Parse(values[3]);
        y = int.Parse(values[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the help! How do I, as I've said above, get an individual part, say the fourth number in each line? To me, I can't see how I specify the `n`th occurence of a number to use in setting the location, size etc.

Comment: Say I want the location x to be the first number, the location y to be the second number, etc.